# Got problems with connecting to telegram bot with C#

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

[image]

Comment: Show some code so we will know how to help you

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    offset = update.Id + 1;
                    if (update.Message == null)
                        continue;
                    var From = update.Message.From.Username;
                    var text = update.Message.Text;
                    long ChatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;
                    label1.Text = string.Format("Sender : {0}\nText : {1}\nChatID : {2}", From, text, ChatId);
                }

Comment: Please post the code as text in the question itself: see [this article](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) for an explanation of why. Also, posting code in the comments section doesn't count because it's unformatted and therefore unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a winforms application you need to use invoke method to do updates to the control on the GUI thread (main thread). You tried to update the control from a background thread.

try something like `label1.Invoke(() =>{ ... });`